# What is the correct way of structuring mySQL code in a nodejs projects?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, relational-database

I have been working on a project lately and using node as my back-end but instead of Mongodb I am using MySQL as my DBMS as I will need it in my project but I am having trouble organizing MySQL queries and can't find a good solution that helps me structure my code and files right. And another issue is that I don't know when to close my connection or if leaving it is a good practice or not.

**NOTE:** I already use express generator for generating my file architecture my only problem is where to place the MySQL related code and what are the best practices for a clean code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model folder and add all your 'tables'.js there.
You can also create a DB.js file, so you can use Mysql from Nodejs and also manipulate it from the prompt:

[Model Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jozsm.png)

I.e of DB connection:
[DB Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZG6b.png)

You can create tables on the way below. ID's, creating date and updated date are created automatically by Nodejs, so you don't need to worry about.

[how to create a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA7A4.png)

You also will need to download mySQL (npm install MySQL --save) and to interact with MySQL (selects, deletes,...)

Another way is create a repository.js and add SQL queries there, but is not really useful since you are using nodejs and it provides you these queries.

Comment: First I was using only MySQL API which confused me but I saw your DB connection example and I noticed that you were using the sequelize API  so I had a look at the sequelize documentation and understood how the API works and how to connect to a database through it and it's file structure is similar to that the MDN tutorial used with mongoose API, thanks a lot for the help.